# Azure Diagnostics + Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, azure-web-app-service, nxlog

Does anyone have a good solution for moving Azure Diagnostics, primarily Azure Websites logs, via Logstash to Elasticsearch?

If Logstash doesnt support it, is there any other tool that does the job? Without too much customization.

Comment: We just added some samples showing how to get the Azure Diagnostics data to elasticsearch using logstash here -> https://github.com/mspnp/semantic-logging/tree/v3/ELK Its still a little light on documentation we will continue to add to it.
Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

As with anything logstash -> elasticsearch, it would depend on what format the logs came in. I assume you have managed to handle passing the logs in to logstash using something like nxlog, you just need to filter them to get them in to elasticsearch?

Without seeing an example, or series of examples, of the logs entries and knowing what you want to get out of the logs, it's difficult to give advice other than, read the documentation, figure out what you want to get out of the logs, then write your own filters. If you get stuck, there is always #logstash on freenode, we're quite active in there.

Comment: This pretty much solved it for me. https://github.com/mspnp/semantic-logging/tree/v3/ELK